# Very high RX errors dropped and frame in eth1 interface

Tags: linux, nic

I'm seeing a NIC hang-up/crash on my server and every time i check ifconfig output, it gives me very high errors, dropped and frame:

$ ifconfig eth1
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:A4:37:A2
          inet6 addr: fe80::225:90ff:fea4:37a2/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:438813 **errors:295321951204200 dropped:49220325200700** overruns:0 **frame:196881300802800**
          TX packets:459806 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:52727916 (50.2 MiB)  TX bytes:419213796 (399.7 MiB)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:df900000-df920000

And when i check the interface:

$ grep "" /sys/class/net/eth1/*

/sys/class/net/eth1/addr_assign_type:0

/sys/class/net/eth1/address:00:25:90:a4:37:a2

/sys/class/net/eth1/addr_len:6

/sys/class/net/eth1/broadcast:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

/sys/class/net/eth1/carrier:0

/sys/class/net/eth1/dev_id:0x0

/sys/class/net/eth1/dormant:0

/sys/class/net/eth1/duplex:unknown

/sys/class/net/eth1/features:0x110ba9

/sys/class/net/eth1/flags:0x1103

/sys/class/net/eth1/ifindex:3

/sys/class/net/eth1/iflink:3

/sys/class/net/eth1/link_mode:0

/sys/class/net/eth1/mtu:1500

/sys/class/net/eth1/operstate:down

/sys/class/net/eth1/speed:-1

/sys/class/net/eth1/tx_queue_len:1000

/sys/class/net/eth1/type:1

/sys/class/net/eth1/uevent:INTERFACE=eth1

/sys/class/net/eth1/uevent:IFINDEX=3

Kernel: 2.6.32-431.5.1.el6.centos.plus.x86_64

At first, i did a *modprobe -r module; modprobe module* to reload the driver, and to reset the stats but after which it tells me that eth1 device is not present anymore on the system.

I can't say for sure if it's a NIC issue because this happens to multiple servers. But a reboot solves the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Are those "multiple server" sharing something like, are they connected to the same switch/uplink ?

Comment: Yes, both servers are connected on the same switch.

Comment: It is possible that the switch (or some particular ports of it) are faulty. I am not confident with network device troubleshooting though. swap it for a new one maybe ?